# Apple Maps went down several hours - did it affect Core Location Api calls?

Tags: ios

This is not a programming question, but please be easy on me.

You might have read heard the Apple maps service went down several hours on June 15th in the morning (reports vary from 8:00 ET - 11:00 ET). Strangely, our app, which uses a geofence, was reported not working by many users, and  our server logs show a significant drop of requests.

Anybody knows the core location api was also affected by this?

Comment: Your app surely keeps logs, why not check there?

Comment: We acknowledged the problem about 3 days later and don't have any devices here who were active at that time, so I guess we have no logs.

Comment: I presume your app is back to functioning correctly; if your app uses any type of mapping then it's plausible that Core Location could have been affected also. It's difficult to say though without knowing what the actual problem was...

Comment: yes it´s back to functioning now. I know the question is a bit off-topic I really just wanted to know if someone has some more information on this problem, not particularly for my app, but in general.